# Fabric.js Transparent Image isn't hoverable

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

I add an Image (png) with a transparent background on my canvas. The Image contain an rectangle with a blue border. If I take the mouse over the image: the mouse is only active when the mouse is over the border but not when the mouse is over the transparent part (inside the rectangle).

```
var options = {
    top: (intRows * intPixelSize) - 87 + intPixelSize,
    left: intCols * intPixelSize - 23,
    id: id,
};
var imgc = new fabric.Image.fromURL('../files/content/pin.png', function(oImg) {
    oImg.set(options);
    oImg.hasControls = false;
    oImg.hasBorders = false;
    canvas.add(oImg);
});
```